# Swift 3D Touch Quick Action not loading requested url

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm new to Swift, and trying my hands with UIWebView app that loads default url, with option to perform quick action and load a different url.

Problem is when I request the quick action url, code executes but the new url is not loading. So I'm missing something in the flow somewhere.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = UIWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("view did load")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "google.com")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        webView.delegate = self
    }

    func loadUrl2() {
        loadView()
        let url = NSURL(string: "example.com")
        print(url)
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I was experimenting and added loadView to loadUrl2, as I was getting

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

before that.

Comment: On which line do you get that `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`?

Comment: I must have changed something else as well, as now I can't regenerate it. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited to Include loading secondary link:**

Here are the changes and files you'll need to make to the `App Delegate`

```
enum ShortcutIdentifier: String {
        case OpenNewLink
        case OpenBetterLink

        init?(fullIdentifier: String) {
            guard let shortIdentifier = fullIdentifier.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(rawValue: shortIdentifier)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsAnnotationKey] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        handleShortcut(shortcutItem)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(handleShortcut(shortcutItem))
}

private func handleShortcut(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    let shortcutType = shortcutItem.type
    guard let ShortcutIdentifier = ShortcutIdentifier(fullIdentifier: shortcutType) else {
        return false
    }
    return selectLinkForIdentifier(ShortcutIdentifier)
}

private func selectLinkForIdentifier(identifier: ShortcutIdentifier) -> Bool {
    guard let mainView = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController else {
        return false
    }

    switch identifier {
    case .OpenNewLink:
        mainView.urlString = "http://www.bing.com"
        mainView.loadWebView(mainView.urlString)
        return true

    case.OpenBetterLink:
        mainView.urlString = "http://www.duckduckgo.com"
        mainView.loadWebView(mainView.urlString)
        return true
    }
}
```

I also made changes in the `MainVC`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
var urlString: String? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpWebView()
    webView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)
}


func setUpWebView() {
    webView = UIWebView()
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    loadWebView(urlString)
}

func loadWebView(var urlString: String?) {
    if urlString == nil {
        urlString = "http://www.google.com"
    }

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString!)
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    webView.loadRequest(req)

}
```

}

Be sure to add NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary to your .plist and add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key set to YES.

I tested it and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. This works indeed. I have it working in this state. My question is about going to different url if I tap the Quick Action, loadUrl2 that is.

Comment: Is the webView on your main view controller in your actual app?

Comment: Yes it is on the main view

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I updated my answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Oh I'm more sorry. Got busy for couple of days, and last night my Macbook stopped charging. So there is another problem to deal with for me :(. Can't test it now

Comment: No worries. Check it when you can. I've been tasting it on my device and it seems to work fine